# xml file reading and binding the data to listbox control on button's click event in wp7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm very new to WP7 app developing and trying to read and bind the xml file data to listbox control on the button's click event.

Could somebody help me out this.

Here's my xml file format:
I want to bind the description tag of this xml to listbox control when we click the button.

```
<ROOT>
<COMPANY NAME="Mercedes Benz">
<Car NAME="A-Class—Hatchback">
<Description>
<![CDATA[ Mercedes Benz will launch the sporty A-Class hatchback, its entry level variant based on the MFA platform for the European market in September 2012.]]>
</Description> 
<COLOR>Red</COLOR>
<Car NAME="Mercedes-Benz G-Class">
<Description>
<![CDATA[ It's the midweek hump and for many a first day back to work, time to jump to action, here's a Mercedes-Benz G-Class in action to inspire to push on to the end of the week!]]>
</Description> 
<COLOR>BLACK</COLOR>
</COMPANY>
<COMPANY NAME="BMW">
<Car NAME="BMW X1">
<Description>
<![CDATA[ The sporty and elegant design of the all-new three-door model, along with additional engine choices, are distinguishing features that sharpen the unmistakable profile of the all-new BMW 1 Series (3-door) as the recognised standard of sheer driving pleasure in the premium compact car segment.]]>
</Description> 
<COLOR>BLUE</COLOR>
</COMPANY>
</ROOT>
```

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sudh

Answer (score 0):

See this Tutorial it will help You

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-xml-reading-filtering-and-databinding